# Getting the error when using json Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 "Valid fragment

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, web-services

I am writing the code as follows

```
-(void)changePwd:(NSString*)userId oldPassword:(NSString*)oldPwd newPwd:(NSString*)newPwd delegate:(id)aDelegate
{
self.delegate = aDelegate;

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ChangePassword/?uid=%@&OldPwd=%@&NewPwd=%@",kServerURL,userId,oldPwd,newPwd];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: strURL]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[self sendRequest:request];
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
(null) -----  error :Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 "Valid fragment, but not JSON" UserInfo=0x10d2532a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Valid fragment, but not JSON}
```

but when i use the link in browser i am getting the response as follows when success

```
"Success"
```

and when failed as follows

```
"Failed"
```

Comment: When/Where does the error happen? Is it in the code you posted, or in a method of your delegate? Can you log what this method receives? Also, I'm not sure that pure "Success" and "Failed" strings can be considered as plain JSON...

Comment: Also a side note, in case you also manage the server-side of your app, please note it is not a good practice to put passwords in GET requests, visible in the URL. Technically, if you're using HTTPS, passwords are indeed equally encrypted as they would be with a POST request, but GET requests are visible to the user (in a browser address bar), so someone who spies over the shoulder of a legitimate user might catch both his old and new passwords ; and GET requests are also often logged in clear with the full query string in HTTP server logs...

Comment: I am getting the error message in delegate method ..Here is the message     result :(null) -----  error :Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 "Valid fragment, but not JSON" UserInfo=0x112833e70 {NSLocalizedDescription=Valid fragment, but not JSON}

Comment: Again, I'm not sure "Success" and "Failed" are acceptable JSON results for your JSON library. You can try separately to give your JSON library a string like the one you're receiving from the server, and see if it crashes. Like that: `SBJson4Parser *p = [[SBJson4Parser alloc] init]; [p parse:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Success"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`